# How to incorporate EL wire into a standard circuit?

Tags: el-wire

I am trying to integrate some EL wire into a standard circuit but having trouble - I have some standard copper wire with a main supply and want that to run into an inverter (as I need one) and then a number of EL wires so that I can identify where there are breaks in the circuit.

Does this sound possible and do you know if it has already been done?  I assume that the answer is yes...

I have built a prototype from some parts ordered online but not getting very far with it!

Comment: Can you draw a schematic please, and include links to the datasheets for the inverter and EL wire? I can't picture what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little new to electronics - what's the best way to draw that for you?

Comment: There is a schematic editor built-in to the box you used to ask the question. Click on the icon that looks like a tiny schematic.

Comment: what is a `standard circuit`?

Answer (score 2):

This has been done, if you want to see an example go [to sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12781) and look at the EL wire switching board. They run an inverter off board and switch the circuit with an isolator and triac(to prevent the high voltage from coming in contact with other parts of the circuit).

[image]
Source: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12781